# Apache 2.2 - no PHP involved, high memory consumption

Tags: apache-2.2

My Apache 2.2 module (Windows) seem to be liking memory, Task Manager shows constant growth in memory until ~2GB are reached, then it crashes. I am not using PHP at all, this is not a website but a module acting as a server. A number of barcode scanning devices will send request to this server, and this server will do inserts, updates, deletes, queries on database. I am seeing the issue if I have 10-15 devices working at the same time.

I am using FastMM to detect memory leaks in my Apache module and FastMM is not reporting any leaks. If I intentionally introduce one, I can see a leak being cought by FastMM.

That tells me that Apache is not releasing memory to OS and this happens under certain circumstances only. If I have 1-2 devices only, then this issue is not happening. So, my guess is that it is caused by high number of requests sent to Apache.

As a temporary solution, I am using PowerShell (version 2.0 or 4.0, depending on machine) script to restart Apache when a memory threshold is reached. My PowerShell script is doing this to stop apache process and service and to start it (if memory has reached ca 0.8GB) and this all works, I tested it:

```
# If working set of httpd or httpd#1 is greater than threshold, stop and start
if($procobj.workingset -gt $Threshold)
{
# $ProcName is name of process reported by PowerShell (as httpd, httpd#1, httpd#2, ...)
echo $("Memory for " + $ProcName + " exceeds Threshold");

# Stop httpd process
stop-process -name $MyHTTPD -force

# Stop service $ServiceName (this is name of service in Windows->Services)
echo $("---> Stopping service: " + $ServiceName);
stop-Service $ServiceName;

# Start service $ServiceName (this is name of service in Windows->Services)
echo $("---> Starting service: " + $ServiceName);
start-Service $ServiceName;
}
```

As you can see, I am stopping httpd process, then stopping Apache service, then starting the service which will spawn new httpd process.

Also, here are the Apache settings I am using:

```
#Commented out these 3 in httpd.conf
#KeepAlive On
#MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
#KeepAliveTimeout 3000

#these are in mod_mpm
# WinNT MPM
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
ThreadsPerChild 300
#MaxRequestsPerChild 0
MaxRequestsPerChild 50
#According to Apache documentation, if you get "An operation was
#attempted on something that is not a socket), you should use this to
#disable AcceptEx() WinSock v2 API. See:
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_winnt.html
Win32DisableAcceptEx
</IfModule>
```

I am aware that this should be temporary solution but right now, the problem is that I can not detect any leaks although Task Manager shows constant growth in memory.  So, I am looking for a ways to minimize the impact by having graceful restarts.  I am not sure my settings above for Apache are good enough, am I missing some that could help me.  I am also not sure my powershell will restart gracefully, so I am looking for suggestions on how to deal with this.

I also see lots of entries in my error.log like this

```
[warn] pid file C:/Handheld/Apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

, which I bellieve are probably caused by my script restarting Apache.

Much Appreciated,

Comment: If your application is not PHP, what is it?

Comment: Hi Michael, this is not a web app.  It is a webservice app where a custom module receives requests sent from devices.  There is no PHP involved here at all.  The server (.so) module is written in Delphi, the clients are in .NETCF3.5 C# but I dont think these details are important.  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you think they are unimportant? They are the obvious prime suspect of your memory leak!

Comment: regardless, PHP is not a suspect

Comment: Noibody ever said PHP was a suspect, so I don't understand why you bring it up again. It is your Apache module written in Delphi which is the suspect.

Comment: The reason I say no PHP is used is that I read lots of posts talking about PHP causing memory leaks.  My module is causing the "leak" but as described above, I can not discover that leak using a memory manager like FastMM (as explained above).  I also read somewhere that apache will not release memory to OS creating high memory consumption.  Regardless of leak or high consumption, the memory goes up and if I would not restart it with my script, it would reach ~2GB.  So, my problem is that I dont know what to look for to figure out where it leaks (as FastMM reports none).  Thanks,

Comment: Thanks to people providing helpful answers, at least I found that starting/stopping service from Powershell like I do above may not be a good idea.  A better way is to use httpd -k restart to restart it gracefully.  So, for those that might need something like this, instead of 3 lines above (stop-process, stop-service, start-service), replace them with call to your httpd.exe like this: C:\your\path\to\Apache\bin\httpd.exe -k restart -n "YOURSERVICENAME" -f "C:\your\path\to\Apache\conf\httpd-YOURNAME.conf";.  If you use default service name, then just alleverything after and including "-n".